# like a List<string> but keeps the strings ordered?

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I want something like a List<string>, but whenever I do an "Add", it keeps the list sorted.  Any ideas?

Comment: I want it to start empty and stay sorted each time I Add.

Comment: Just to clarify: Are you only putting things into the list that can be automatically sorted, or do you need to be able to pass in something that defines how to sort?

Comment: strings, so nothing needs to be passed in

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try a [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx) or a [SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx). Both will do what you need to do, but with slightly differing implementations. You can find the differences highlighted [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z658b67%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Note that SortedList and SortedDictionary cannot be accessed by index and do not implement the IList<T> interface.  Both are more like dictionaries than lists.  Specifically, you cannot do SortedList<string>.Add(someString) -- you have to pass in a key and a value.  This is very unnatural for a list-like interface.

Answer (score 3):

The [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx) class?

Answer (score 2):

Use List< T > and call [List< T >.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx).

```
List<string> dinosaurs = new List<string>();

dinosaurs.Add("Pachycephalosaurus");
dinosaurs.Add("Amargasaurus");
dinosaurs.Add("Mamenchisaurus");
dinosaurs.Add("Deinonychus");     

Console.WriteLine("\nSort");
dinosaurs.Sort();
```

EDIT: You could also extend List< T >, override Add, pick one.

**ExtendedList:**

```
public class ExtendedList<T> : List<T>
{
    public new void Add(T t)
    {
        base.Add(t);
        base.Sort();
    }
}
```

**ExtendedList with BinarySearch:**

```
public class ExtendedList<T> : List<T>
{
    public new void Add(T t)
    {
        int index = base.BinarySearch(t);
        if (index < 0)
        {
            base.Insert(~index, t);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I thought of that, but I don't want the sort overhead each time I access the list

Comment: You do understand that whatever you use to automatically sort will have overhead right?

Answer (score 1):

SortedList: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own class, MySortList, that implements IList, and your own interface IMySort

Which would have an added method of AddAndSort(T t)

this wouldn't be interchangable with normal IList however, but it does do what you need to.

Comment: It actually _would_ work if your implementation of `Add` called `AddAndSort`.  And because you're implementing IList, it _would_ be interchangeable with IList... that's the point of separating the interface from the implementation.  You wouldn't need IMySort however.

Comment: Yes but IList does not implement AddAndSort, hence the extra interface. Unless you ignored AddAndSort, and on each add, sort it. Then it would be interchangable with IList

Answer (score 1):

You could extend `List` so that the `Add` method does a binary search to find the correct insertion location, and then add it in there. This should give better performance than overriding `Add` to add and then sort the list. (Btw, `Sort` uses Quicksort, which doesn't necessarily give great performance for this case.)